# Can we use RPi as main router which directly connect to ISP provided broadband cable to access internet?

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-3b+, wireless, raspi-config

Im beginner to RPi and networking as well so i have very basic question for start. i am trying to build a internet wifi router using RPi3 with the help of material available on internet. But i can find documents only related to "How to use RPi as router to access internet through AP". This type of post tell how we can use RPi as extended wifi router only.

But my question is how can i configure my RPi3 which Replace my home router connected to Internet Broadband cable provided by ISP??? And I am able to access internet via RPi's AP from other devices.

Please help me and suggest me what configuration i need to follow to work this out. Waiting for reply.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already connected Ethernet cable between pi and my router and it works fine as extended router. But i want to know that, is it practically possible to physically replace that home router with RPI??

Comment: Thank you @FrankMerrow. i appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot just replace your internet router with a Raspberry Pi. You need at least an additional USB dongle to connect to the service of your internet provider. And that depends on the service that is provided. If it is a cell phone or satellite service like gsm/3G/4G/5G you need a USB/modem dongle. If it is a DSL connection using old copper telephone lines you need a router/modem supporting this and if you have modern optical fiber you need a USB dongle that can connect to it (don't know if it is available).

For mobility it is possible to use a USB/modem dongle for gsm/3G/4G/5G but for the other connections it is easier to use a compatible router which are often given by the provider to connect to his network.

Comment: You could connect the Raspberry Pi to the internet provider's modem and then use the Raspberry Pi as a wireless access point. Not that I'd recommend using a Raspberry Pi for this purpose but it is possible.

Comment: @OleWolf Yes, of course. To connect a local network to the modem, that's what the modem is made for. You can connect any network device to it. I do not understand what you want to say.

Comment: I was basically saying that you can in fact replace your provider's router with a Raspberry Pi if all you want is a wireless access point ... but you probably don't want to do that.

Comment: @OleWolf "*... if all you want is a wireless access point*" without internet access. Ah, that's the point.

Comment: No. The Raspberry Pi has an ethernet port that you can connect to the modem thus getting internet access. In turn, the Raspberry Pi may share this internet access via its WiFi card.

Comment: @OleWolf Your comments are very confusing. One time you want to replace the modem completely by the Raspberry Pi, the other time you want to connect to the modem to get internet access. You cannot connect to a modem that isn't present.

Comment: I don't think I said that the modem could be replaced; please re-read. The provider's router might, but not the modem.